# using jQuery.guid

Tags: javascript, jquery, guid

Can I use the `jQuery.guid` for my own use? I have elements where I need a unique id attr so I just want to set it to `jQuery.guid++` like so:

```
var guid = jQuery.guid++;

$('<a href="#" id="a' + guid + '">link</a>').appendTo('body');
```

Is this safe? Will it break any code or plugins?

Comment: It does not break jQuery. Someone might write a bad plugin that can break if you change jQuery.guid. I would advice againts it though as any new jQuery version might break it. `$.guid` really should not be public.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this code to generate a Guid:

```
'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, 
function(c) 
{
    var r = Math.random() * 16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't break anything, although, if you are going to use `$.guid` as a global variable, there is no need to create yet another variable called `guid`.

Just initialize the `$.guid` once and then use it directly.

```
// initialize once
$.guid= 0;

// use it directly when needed
$('<a href="#" id="a' + ($.guid++) + '">link</a>').appendTo('body');
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems `$.guid` is used internally by jQuery for live events and shouldn't be used for DOM. You should make your own global variable and increment it yourself.

Comment: yeah but the $.guid is already being used by jQuery internally. I would need to reuse whatever value the guid gives me for labels and events so I need to have a copy of the variable.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I really didn't know `$.guid` was used internally. In that case, I would go with what I wrote above, just with another variable name, such as `$.myguid`, to be safe.

Comment: yeah but I'm not sure if jQuery is keeping track of what number it's up to in the event of removing or adding elements or events. I need to know if it's important for any plugins or for it to keep track of events. I don't want it to break any code

Comment: That's why I said to use a different variable name, so that it doesn't mess with `$.guid`. Why would you even want to use a variable jQuery uses internally? If you only need a global unique number, make your own variable and increment it yourself. That should be more then enough for your needs, or am I missing something?

Comment: yeah, I would prefer not to have to make my own variable. I just needed information if it would break anything in jQuery

Comment: Why not just append some random text like an app descriptor to $.guid? it should then be locally unique?